# I get Error in laravel query when i use count(rating) as productRating then it not found productRating Field

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5

I join My product table to review table then i count the  rating of product then put condityion on rating then i got error  that field not found.

Code:

```
  $products = Product::leftjoin('reviews','products.id','=','reviews.productID')
                           ->select('products.*',DB::raw("AVG(rating) as 'productRating'"))
                           ->where('products.status','=',"enable")
                           ->where(function($query) use ($categoriesID,$brands,$priceArray,$ratingArray)
                            {
                                $query->whereIn('categoryID',$categoriesID);
                                if(count($brands) > 0)
                                {
                                    $query->whereIn('brandID',$brands);
                                }
                                $query->whereBetween('productSellingPrice',$priceArray);
                                if(count($ratingArray) > 0)
                                {
                                    $query->whereBetween('productRating',$ratingArray);
                                }
                            })
                        ->groupBy('products.id')
                        ->get();
```

Error :

```
   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'productRating' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `products`.*, AVG(rating) as 'productRating' from `products` left join `reviews` on `products`.`id` = `reviews`.`productID` where `products`.`status` = enable and (`categoryID` in (1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 11, 18, 21, 28, 31) and `productSellingPrice` between 50 and 5000 and `productRating` between 4 and 5) group by `products`.`id`)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is SQL, not laravel, error.

You can not use aggregated field is where clause, you need to use having instead.

```
$products = Product::leftjoin('reviews','products.id','=','reviews.productID')
     ->select('products.*',DB::raw("AVG(rating) as 'productRating'"))
     ->where('products.status','=',"enable")
     ->whereIn('categoryID',$categoriesID)
     ->whereBetween('productSellingPrice',$priceArray)
     ->groupBy('products.id');


if(count($brands) > 0)
{
     $products->whereIn('brandID',$brands);
}

if(count($ratingArray) > 0)
{
    // assume $ratingArray = [$min, $max];
    list($ratingMin, $ratingMax) = $ratingArray;
    $products->having('productRating', '>', $ratingMin);
    $products->having('productRating', '<', $ratingMax);
}

$items = $products->get();
```

Comment: I write this query in laravel can you please suggest me how i write down this query with having clause

Answer (score 1):

thank you Everyone i already  solved it

Code:

```
  $products = Product::leftjoin('reviews','products.id','=','reviews.productID')
                           ->select('products.*',DB::raw("IFNULL(AVG(rating),0) as 'productRating'"))
                           ->where('products.status','=',"enable")
                           ->where(function($query) use ($categoriesID,$brands,$priceArray)
                            {
                                $query->whereIn('categoryID',$categoriesID);
                                if(count($brands) > 0)
                                {
                                    $query->whereIn('brandID',$brands);
                                }
                                $query->whereBetween('productSellingPrice',$priceArray);
                            })
                        ->groupBy('products.id')
                        ->having('productRating', '>=', $startRating)
                        ->having('productRating', '<=', $endRating)
                        ->get();
```